# Convolution of Dirac comb with an exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, convolution, dirac-delta

I have to solve the following convolution:

> $$y(t)=e^{-t}u(t)*\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-2k)$$

Here $\delta(.)$ is Dirac delta function. The summation is:

$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-2k)=\frac12\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(k-\frac t2\right)=\frac12\operatorname{III}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)$$

Here $\operatorname{III}(.)$ is the *Dirac Comb function.*

Now continuing with the definition of convolution, we have:

$$y(t)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\tau}u(\tau)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(\left(k-\frac {t}{2}\right)-\tau\right)\ \mathrm{d}\tau$$

Using the ["sifting" property of the Dirac Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation)

$$\begin{align*}y(t)&=\frac12\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\left(k-\frac {t}{2}\right)}u\left(k-\frac {t}{2}\right)\\ &=\frac12e^{\frac {t}{2}}\sum_{k=\frac {t}{2}}^{\infty}e^{-k}\\ &=\frac12e^{\frac {t}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{e^{\frac {t}{2}}}+\frac{1}{e^{\frac {t}{2}+1}}+\frac{1}{e^{\frac {t}{2}+2}}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \right)\\ &=\frac12\left(1+\frac{1}{e^{1}}+\frac{1}{e^{2}}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \right)=\frac12\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}} \end{align*}$$

> But the answer in my book is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-e^{-2}}e^{-t}$, $0\leq t<2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two mistakes.

1) You get the convolution wrong. It should read
$$ y(t)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\tau}u(\tau)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(\left(k-\frac {t}{2}\right)+\frac12 \tau\right)\ \mathrm{d}\tau$$

2) There is a mistake in the line with $\sum_{k=t/2}^\infty$. Note that $k$ should be an integer!!!

Here, is a correct derivation. Let us start with the definition of the convolution
$$ y(t)= \int e^{-\tau}u(\tau)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-2k-\tau) d\tau \,.$$

Then we use the sifting property to obtain
$$ y(t)=  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2k-t}u(t-2k)\;.$$

Now the summation over $k$ should include the **integers** that are smaller than $t/2$. In particular, for $0\leq t <2$, these include $k\in \{0,-1,-2,\dots\}$. We obtain
$$ y(t)=  \sum_{k=-\infty}^{0} e^{2k-t} = \frac{e^{-t}}{1-e^{-2}}$$
valid for $0\leq t <2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you also show me how to arrive at $$ y(t)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\tau}u(\tau)\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta\left(\left(k-\frac {t}{2}\right)+\frac12 \tau\right)\ \mathrm{d}\tau$$

Comment: The convolution of two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is defined as $\int f(\tau) g(t-\tau) d\tau$. Just plug this in and use that $\delta(2x) = \frac12 \delta(x)\dots$

Comment: @Fabian Hello, does $y$ vanish outside of the interval $[0,2]$ and hence not qualify as a periodic function? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat: it is easy to see that $y(t+2) = y(t)$: so no, $y$ does not vanish outside the interval $[0,2]$.

Comment: @Fabian I was wondering what $u$ exactly is. Initially, I figured that $$u(t)=\begin{cases}1,&0<t<1\\0,&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ but now it seems that I was wrong. What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat: It is the [Heaviside Step Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Answer (score 1):

$$
e^{-t}u(t)*\delta(t-2k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(t-\tau)}u(t-\tau)\delta(\tau-2k)d\tau = e^{-t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\tau}u(t-\tau)\delta(\tau-2k)d\tau=e^{-t}\int_{t}^{\infty}e^{\tau}\delta(\tau-2k)d\tau=e^{-t}e^{-2k}
$$

then

$$
\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-t}u(t)*\delta(t-2k)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}u(t)*\delta(t-2k)=e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{-2k}=e^{-t}\frac{1}{1-e^{-2}}
$$

It is essential the role of $u(t)$!

Comment: The variable in the summation is k, how can you use u(**t**) to change the limits?

Comment: @paulplusx Pay attention to the second to third integrals above.

Comment: @Cesareo Hello, does $y$ vanish outside of the interval $[0,2]$ and hence not qualify as a periodic function? Thank you.